# How to run sql scripts only for specific environment in Flyway community

Tags: flyway

I want to run CREATE USER and GRANT for specific environment.
This can be easily implemented using Jinja template if-else-endif syntax.

```
{% if '${env}' = 'stg' %}
grant test_role to test_user;
{% endif %}
```

As Flyway is Java based tool. Is there any solution we can use in Flyway community?